# Can't Access SOAP Web Service Over HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, soap, ssl, nginx

What I am trying to do is hit a web service (which I built) using SSL. It doesn't seem to be working though. Some relevant information:

- Everything works fine using HTTP. The problem only happens when I use HTTPS.
- The actual error message being output is as follows:

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from  ... : failed to load external entity ...

- The service is implemented in PHP.
- If I run php -m or check phpinfo() openssl appears to be installed properly.
- The SSL certificate seems to be working fine otherwise. I can use HTTPS on the rest of the site; it's just the web service that's having a problem.
- If I try accessing the WSDL via a browser over HTTPS, it works fine. If I try to access one of the SOAP endpoint URLs, then I get the error message.
- I wrote a minimized PHP script to try and make an actual call to the service. It will get the error message when trying to retrieve the WSDL itself.
- Web server is Apache running on Debian
- It doesn't seem to be a code issue. I have comparable code running on the dev server and it works fine there, even using HTTPS.
- Production system is running on a proxy system, with nginx in the front. It seems like this is most likely related to the issue, but no idea where to start solving that problem.

Comment: Is the https certificate valid?

Comment: Are you using the (evil) PHP native SOAP extension (ihateitihateitihateit)? Try [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) instead - I switched and my hair is now gradually growing back.

Comment: Certificate is valid, and also not self-signed. Works for HTTPS on normal website running on same server. Yes, using (evil) native SOAP extension. Could try NuSOAP but doubt that's the issue, as the same test code works on development server. Has to be some configuration issue.

Comment: `Works for HTTPS on normal website running on same server.` - is the service your domain is running on within the scope of the domain of the certificate? Same server != same domain, which matters with SSL certs. Would be interested to know whether you can retrieve the raw XML with cURL or something - find out whether it is a parse error in the WSDL or a network transmission problem. If the latter, cURL will also give you more helpful error messages.

Comment: Service runs under scope of same domain. Main site is like www.site.com and service is like www.site.com/service/  However, cURL request did give interesting error message: curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol going to start googling this for insight

Comment: May I ask what version of PHP you are running? Please also verify that you have connected to the correct port, almost seems like you are hitting something that is not SSL enabled, or if you are running on a *very* old PHP version it may be that the server want's to use SSLv3 and PHP does not support it.

Comment: Is php 5.3. More than likely nginx is not supporting a SSL protocol that cURL is using or expecting. Could be a bit of a red herring. My other line of support is telling me it's definitely something with how nginx is forwarding requests to the apache servers. Not sure what configuration that would be though.

Comment: I take it then that you are using an Nginx reverse-proxy? Regardless, if cURL is giving you error 35, that *should* indicate a problem in SSL configuration or the certificate. At the stage where you get [error 35](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLESSLCONNECTERROR), a communication link has not been opened (`A problem occurred somewhere in the SSL/TLS handshake.`), so Nginx has not received a request, so does not know it needs to be forwarded/where to forward it to. My next step would be Wireshark, although you will need the private key to make any sense of it...

Comment: Yea, that's interesting. Using web browser I can see requests hit the nginx access log, but curl it doesn't. I'm still open to suggestions but my investigation is going on a different trajectory now. Probably I should have posted this on serverfault anyways = (

Comment: I think serverfault is a good idea, possibly webmasters? Voting to move to SF, you can flag it for moderator attention if you don't want to wait/hope for 5 people to vote the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to point out this is likely related to your nginx configuration and for SSL there are a couple of good spots to start looking:

1. Verify your listening port on nginx is 443
2. Verify your proxy location is 127.0.0.1:80 (port 80 because it's HTTP, unless you customized it)
3. If you are using CentOS, I've found iptables to be the culprit of many problems. Sometimes I just forget to open up port 443 in the firewall. To configure, go to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables/` and add a firewall rule.

and last but not least....

I found this nifty guide for SOAP over SSL :) http://soapoverhttps.blogspot.ca/

Comment: Your point 1 is an abbreviated version of the actual problem. For other inquiring minds, I got help from our part time server admin and he figured out that the problem was two fold: a) There's actually two proxy servers - a primary and a fail over. The fail over's keepalived configuration was wrong so it was handling requests when it shouldn't. b) Because it was a fail over it was listening on a default port and binding SSL traffic to a non-SSL port. Anyways, no sense in accepting my own answer so I'm marking your the accepted answer.